# Getting name of logrotate file?

Tags: bash, logrotate

Let me start by saying I'm very new to linux and bash scripting, only been at this for 2 weeks so assume I know nothing!

For development reasons, I need to copy a log file to another location and name, here's my logrotate file:

```
/pub/share/logs/results.txt {
    daily
    rotate 30
    dateext
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    postrotate
        sh /pub/share/scripts/result_rotate.sh $1 > /dev/null
    endscript
}
```

And the bash script is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=$(date +%Y%m%d)
cp $1-$date /pub/share/reports/data.log
```

I don't know if I *have* to put this in a script file or if I can just type that inside the postrotate block, but for now this works.

It passes the name of the file to be rotated but does so after it's already renamed it with the date extension, hence the date code above.  Is this a safe way to do this? Could there ever be an instance where it might fail to match up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, why not, you can directly write in *postrotate* block:

```
cp $1-$(date +%Y%m%d) /pub/share/reports/data.log >/dev/null
```

in a worse situation where logrotation happened for example with today's date and *postrotate*  posted to run in next day's date, so our `cp` command will not get that file to copy. for that you can get one day older file always instead of today's date rotated file:

```
cp $1-$(date -d'-1day' +%Y%m%d) /pub/share/reports/data.log >/dev/null
```

or of course you can copy those both files, meaning today's date and yesterday's date files.